# innerHTML not working after getImageData

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getimagedata

I used the code for displaying in a video tag what the webcam shows.

If the webcam access is supported, I call this function every second:

```
function refresh() {
  var h = video.height;
  var w = video.width;
  var img = video.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
  document.getElementById('text_01').innerHTML = "!";
}
```

With var video being

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
```

The problem is that text of "text_01" changes successfully when I place these lines like this:

```
document.getElementById('text_01').innerHTML = "!";
img = video.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
```

but not like this:

```
img = video.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
document.getElementById('text_01').innerHTML = "!";
```

Is it some kind of restriction using innerHTML after some functions?

Comment: Are you declaring the variable `img` anywhere? Are there any errors being thrown by the call to `getImageData`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I already edited it, but that's not the problem.

Comment: getImageData is a method of a canvas' 2d rendering context not a video element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getImageData` is a function of `<canvas>` elements, not `<video>` elements. If you checked your browser console, you'd see something along the lines of `getImageData is not a function`.

This is why the `innerHTML` is not set - due to the error, the code stops.